# Drawing multiple sprites with a for loop xna 4.0

Tags: c#, for-loop, xna, drawing, sprite

I am currently working on a platforming game and I am trying to draw 40 items in one screenstate, but I don't want to hard code them all. Here's what I've tried so far:

Sprite class:

```
       class Sprite
{
    //texture, position and color
    public Texture2D texture;
    public Vector2 position;
    public Color color;
}
```

Definiton:

```
Sprite levelboxbg;
int LevelBoxX = 20;
```

Loading:

```
        levelboxbg = new Sprite();
        levelboxbg.texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("LevelBoxBeta");
        levelboxbg.position = new Vector2(0, 0);
        levelboxbg.color = Color.White;
```

Execution:

```
     public void DrawLevelBoxes(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(levelboxbg.texture, new Vector2(LevelBoxX + 20 ,0), levelboxbg.color);
            LevelBoxX += 20;
        }
    }
```

I then call the method in my draw function.

Visual studio has given me 0 errors for this and it will run; however, when I get to the screen where it's supposed to draw the boxes, it draws them all but only for a fraction of a second, then they dissipate.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Try to set LevelBoxX = 20 just before the for-loop?

Comment: @Ulf Kristiansen Thank you so much, that fixed it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your LevelBoxX goes to infinity, so the boxes are running out of the screen pretty fast. You can reset LevelBoxX just before the for-loop like so:

```
public void DrawLevelBoxes(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    LevelBoxX = 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(levelboxbg.texture, new Vector2(LevelBoxX + 20 ,0), levelboxbg.color);
        LevelBoxX += 20;
    }
}
```

Or just declare a local variable:

```
public void DrawLevelBoxes(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    int counter = 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(levelboxbg.texture, new Vector2(counter + 20 ,0), levelboxbg.color);
        counter += 20;
    }
}
```